# Help cleaning up asp.net mvc web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have finished developing my app and now I want to deploy it.. what changes should I make to this web.config file to make as clean as possible?.. its asp.net mvc 1.0

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!-- 
        Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
        web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
        the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
        A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
        machine.config.comments usually located in 
        \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
    -->
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
            <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                        <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                        <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                        <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                        <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    </sectionGroup>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </configSections>
        <appSettings/>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyBD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        </connectionStrings>
        <system.web>
            <!-- 
                Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
                symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
                affects performance, set this value to true only 
                during development.
        -->
            <compilation debug="false">
                <assemblies>
                    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                </assemblies>
            </compilation>
            <!--
                The <authentication> section enables configuration 
                of the security authentication mode used by 
                ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
            <authentication mode="Forms">
                <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"/>
            </authentication>
        <membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="CustomMembershipProvider"
                 type="MyProject.AspNet.MembershipProvider.CustomMembershipProvider"
                 connectionStringName="ConnectionString"
                 enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                 enablePasswordReset="true"
                 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                 requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                 passwordFormat="Hashed"
                 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                 minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
                 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                 passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                 passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
                 applicationName="/"/>
          </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
          <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
          </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add connectionStringName="ConnectionString" name="CustomRoleProvider"
             type="MyProject.AspNet.RoleProvider.CustomRoleProvider" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
            <!--
                The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
                of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
                during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
                it enables developers to configure html error pages 
                to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

            <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
                <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
                <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
            </customErrors>
        -->
        <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
          <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
          <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Home/Error" />
        </customErrors>
            <pages>
                <controls>
                    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                </controls>
                <namespaces>
                    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
                    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
                    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
                    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
                    <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
                    <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
            <add namespace="xVal.Html"/>
            <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI"/>
                </namespaces>
            </pages>
            <httpHandlers>
                <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
                <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
                <add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </httpHandlers>
            <httpModules>
                <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </httpModules>
        </system.web>
        <system.net>
            <mailSettings>
                <smtp from="webmaster@MyCompany.com">
                    <network host="127.0.0.1"/>
                </smtp>
            </mailSettings>
        </system.net>
        <system.codedom>
            <compilers>
                <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
                </compiler>
                <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                    <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
                </compiler>
            </compilers>
        </system.codedom>
        <!-- 
            The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
            Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
      -->
        <system.webServer>
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
                <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
                <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
                <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </modules>
            <handlers>
                <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
                <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
                <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
                <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
                <remove name="MvcHttpHandler"/>
                <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
                <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: I always start by stripping out comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are targetting **.NET 4**
   then you can get rid of a lot of
   this stuff. It would probably be
   easiest to create a brand new MVC
   project targetting 4.0 and look at
   the default web.config there.
2. If you are targetting **.NET 3.5**
   everything in here looks pretty
   standard. I'm assuming you are using
   membership, roles, profiles, the
   various namespaces etc. in your
   application.

   You might be able to get rid of some
   of the reference assemblies
   (System.Data.Linq, System.Xml.Linq,
   etc) if you are not using their
   features. You could also probably
   remove the control tag mapping if
   you don't have any WebForms pages in
   your app.

   If you are deploying to IIS 6 you
   could get rid of the
   `<system.webServer>` section but you
   might want to leave it in in case
   you ever upgrade the server.

Comment: Well it's just that after reading http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/25/clean-web-config-files-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

I just thought there was probably something very nasty happening with my web.config

Comment: Added some clarification for for different versions of .NET